# Write out the number "5" as "Five" in VB Script?

Tags: asp-classic

is it as all possible to write out an output integer i'm getting with letters in classic asp?

so for example if my result is 5 i want to output "Five"

or if it's twenty, i need it to show "Twenty"

the results could be infinite so writing an array for look up purposes wouldn't work.

is there a work around for this?

Comment: Here's an algorithm (Java though): http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html.

Comment: A quick google search gave me the following: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15934/How-to-convert-a-numeric-value-or-currency-to-Engl this should show you how you can do it in c#

Comment: C#, Java? This is a Classic ASP question, these suggestions are completely off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I robbed this from an MS KB article many moons ago, It sort of does the trick, could use a few tweaks on its grammar.

```vb
response.Write ConvertCurrencyToEnglish("213123")


Function ConvertCurrencyToEnglish (ByVal MyNumber)
   Dim Temp
   Dim Dollars, Cents
   Dim DecimalPlace, Count

   ReDim Place(9)

   Place(2) = " Thousand "
   Place(3) = " Million "
   Place(4) = " Billion "
   Place(5) = " Trillion "

   'Convert MyNumber to a string, trimming extra spaces.
   MyNumber = Trim(CStr(MyNumber))

   'Find decimal place.
   DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

   'If we find decimal place...
   If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
      'Convert cents
      Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
      Cents = ConvertTens(Temp)
      'Strip off cents from remainder to convert.
      MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
   End If

   Count = 1

   Do While MyNumber <> ""
      'Convert last 3 digits of MyNumber to English dollars.
      Temp = ConvertHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
      If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
      If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
         'Remove last 3 converted digits from MyNumber.
         MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
      Else
         MyNumber = ""
      End If
      Count = Count + 1
   Loop

   'Clean up dollars.
   Select Case Dollars
      Case ""
         Dollars = "No Dollars"
      Case "One"
         Dollars = "One Dollar"
      Case Else
         Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
   End Select

   'Clean up cents.
   Select Case Cents
      Case ""
         Cents = " And No Cents"
      Case "One"
         Cents = " And One Cent"
      Case Else
         Cents = " And " & Cents & " Cents"
   End Select

   'ConvertCurrencyToEnglish = Dollars & Cents
   ConvertCurrencyToEnglish = Dollars & Cents
End Function

Private Function ConvertHundreds (ByVal MyNumber)
   Dim Result

   'Exit if there is nothing to convert.
   If CInt(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function

   'Append leading zeros to number.
   MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

   'Do we have a hundreds place digit to convert?
   If Left(MyNumber, 1) <> "0" Then
      Result = ConvertDigit(Left(MyNumber, 1)) & " Hundred "
   End If

   'Do we have a tens place digit to convert?
   If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
      Result = Result & ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
   Else
      'If not, then convert the ones place digit.
      Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
   End If

   ConvertHundreds = Trim(Result)
End Function

Private Function ConvertTens (ByVal MyTens)
   Dim Result

   'Is value between 10 and 19?
   If CInt(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 1 Then
      Select Case CInt(MyTens)
         Case 10: Result = "Ten"
         Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
         Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
         Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
         Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
         Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
         Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
         Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
         Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
         Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
         Case Else
      End Select
   Else
      '... otherwise it's between 20 and 99.
      Select Case CInt(Left(MyTens, 1))
         Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
         Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
         Case 4: Result = "Forty "
         Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
         Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
         Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
         Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
         Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
         Case Else
      End Select
      'Convert ones place digit.
      Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
   End If

   ConvertTens = Result
End Function

Private Function ConvertDigit (ByVal MyDigit)
   Select Case CInt(MyDigit)
      Case 1: ConvertDigit = "One"
      Case 2: ConvertDigit = "Two"
      Case 3: ConvertDigit = "Three"
      Case 4: ConvertDigit = "Four"
      Case 5: ConvertDigit = "Five"
      Case 6: ConvertDigit = "Six"
      Case 7: ConvertDigit = "Seven"
      Case 8: ConvertDigit = "Eight"
      Case 9: ConvertDigit = "Nine"
      Case Else: ConvertDigit = ""
   End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

This script can be saved to `num2txt.vbs` for testing:

```vb
Option Explicit

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Numbers to words -- proof of concept, nerfed to serve up to a trillion  '
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Dim i, j, a, b, c, d, e, f, s

a = array( _
    "zero", _
    "one", _
    "two", _
    "three", _
    "four", _
    "five", _
    "six", _
    "seven", _
    "eight", _
    "nine", _
    "ten", _
    "eleven", _
    "twelve", _
    "thirteen", _
    "fourteen", _
    "fifteen", _
    "sixteen", _
    "seventeen", _
    "eighteen", _
    "nineteen" _
)

b = array( _
    "twenty", _
    "thirty", _
    "forty", _
    "fifty", _
    "sixty", _
    "seventy", _
    "eighty", _
    "ninety" _
)

c = array( _
    "hundred", _
    "thousand", _
    "million", _
    "billion", _
    "trillion" _
)

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Returns the text for numbers; this can definitely be optimised further  '
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function WhatAmI(i)
    Dim s

    If i >= 1000000000000 Then
        If Len(i) = 15 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 3)) & " " & c(4)
        If Len(i) = 14 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 2)) & " " & c(4)
        If Len(i) = 13 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 1)) & " " & c(4)

        If Right(i, 12) <> "000000000000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 12), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 12), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 12), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f) & " " & c(3)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If

        If Right(i, 9) <> "000000000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 9), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 9), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 9), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f) & " " & c(2)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If

        If Right(i, 6) <> "000000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 6), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 6), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 6), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f) & " " & c(1)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If

        If Right(i, 3) <> "000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 3), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 3), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 3), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf i >= 1000000000 Then
        If Len(i) = 12 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 3)) & " " & c(3)
        If Len(i) = 11 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 2)) & " " & c(3)
        If Len(i) = 10 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 1)) & " " & c(3)

        If Right(i, 9) <> "000000000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 9), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 9), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 9), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f) & " " & c(2)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If

        If Right(i, 6) <> "000000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 6), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 6), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 6), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f) & " " & c(1)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If

        If Right(i, 3) <> "000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 3), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 3), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 3), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf i >= 1000000 Then
        If Len(i) = 9 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 3)) & " " & c(2)
        If Len(i) = 8 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 2)) & " " & c(2)
        If Len(i) = 7 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 1)) & " " & c(2)

        If Right(i, 6) <> "000000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 6), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 6), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 6), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f) & " " & c(1)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If

        If Right(i, 3) <> "000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 3), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 3), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 3), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf i >= 1000 Then
        If Len(i) = 6 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 3)) & " " & c(1)
        If Len(i) = 5 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 2)) & " " & c(1)
        If Len(i) = 4 Then s = WhatAmI(Left(i, 1)) & " " & c(1)

        If Right(i, 3) <> "000" Then
            d = Mid(Right(i, 3), 1, 1)
            e = Mid(Right(i, 3), 2, 1)
            f = Mid(Right(i, 3), 3, 1)

            If d <> 0 Then
                s = s & ", "
                s = s & WhatAmI(d & e & f)
            ElseIf e <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(e & f)
            ElseIf f <> 0 Then
                s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(f)
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf i >= 100 Then
        s = a(Left(i, 1)) & " " & c(0)
        If Right(i, 2) <> "00" Then s = s & " and " & WhatAmI(Right(i, 2))
    ElseIf i >= 90 Then
        s = b(7)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf i >= 80 Then
        s = b(6)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf i >= 70 Then
        s = b(5)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf i >= 60 Then
        s = b(4)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf i >= 50 Then
        s = b(3)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf i >= 40 Then
        s = b(2)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf i >= 30 Then
        s = b(1)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf (i >= 20) Then
        s = b(0)
        If Right(i, 1) > 0 Then s = s & "-" & a(Right(i, 1))
    ElseIf (i > 9) Then
        s = a(i)
    ElseIf (i >= 0 AND i <= 9) Then
        s = a(i)
    End If
    WhatAmI = s
End Function

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Ensure input is really numeric                                          '
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Function is_numeric(s)
    Dim i, c

    is_numeric = True

    If IsNull(s) OR s = "" Then
        is_numeric = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If s = "" Then
        is_numeric = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
            If Asc(c) < 48 OR Asc(c) > 57 Then
            is_numeric = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

i = InputBox("Enter the number you wish to convert:", "Numbers to Text")

If i <> "" Then i = Replace(i, ",", "") ' In case input was 1,100 or something '

If Len(i) > 15 Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, numbers larger than a trillion aren't supported", 0, "Fail"
End If

If NOT is_numeric(i) Then
    MsgBox "That is not a valid number... Integers only, please", 0, "Fail"
Else
    i = CDbl(i)

    MsgBox FormatNumber(i, 0) & " = " & WhatAmI(i), 0, "Converted"
End If
```

Example outputs:

```
110,314 = one hundred and ten thousand, three hundred and fourteen

540,610,333 = five hundred and forty million, six hundred and ten thousand, three hundred and thirty-three
```

Comment: For the `WhatAmI()` function. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a legacy system using VBScript and need to translate numbers to words. I used the code posted by [Heavencore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856066/heavencore) (see answer with most votes); however I needed this  to be in spanish so I made the adjustments. It's important to note that most spanish speaking countries use long scale naming system (see [powers of ten scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales))

```
function ConvertAmountToSpanish (MyNumber)
  Dim Temp
  Dim Dollars, Cents
  Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    

  'Convert MyNumber to a string, trimming extra spaces.
  MyNumber = Trim(CStr(MyNumber))
  
  'Find decimal place.
  DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
  'If we find decimal place...
  If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    'Convert cents
    Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
      Cents = ConvertTens(Temp)
      'Strip off cents from remainder to convert.
      MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
  End If

  Dollars = ConvertIntegerToSpanish(MyNumber)
  
  'Clean up dollars.
  Select Case Dollars
    Case ""
      Dollars = "Cero Pesos"
    Case "Un"
      Dollars = "Un Peso"
    Case Else
      Dollars = Dollars & " pesos"
    End Select

   'Clean up cents.
    Select Case Cents
      Case ""
        Cents = " con Cero Centavos"
      Case "One"
        Cents = " con un centavo"
      Case Else
        Cents = " con " & Cents & " centavos"
    End Select
  
  ConvertAmountToSpanish = Dollars & Cents
end function

Function ConvertIntegerToSpanish (MyNumber)
  Dim Temp
  Dim NumberText
  Dim Count

  ReDim Place(9)

  Place(2) = " Mil "
  Place(3) = " Millones "
  Place(4) = " Mil Millones "
  Place(5) = " Billones "
  Place(6) = " Mil Billones "

  'Convert MyNumber to a string, trimming extra spaces.
  MyNumber = Trim(CStr(MyNumber))

  Count = 1

  Do While MyNumber <> ""
      'Convert last 3 digits of MyNumber to English dollars.
      Temp = ConvertHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
      If Temp <> "" Then
        If Temp = "Uno" Then
          If Count = 2 OR Count = 4 Then NumberText = LCase(Place(Count)) & NumberText
          If Count = 3 OR Count = 5 Then NumberText =  "Un" & LCase(Mid(Place(Count),1,Len(Place(Count))-3)) & " " & NumberText
        Else
          If Count > 1 AND Count < 7 Then
            NumberText = Temp & LCase(Place(Count)) & NumberText
          Else
            NumberText = Temp & Place(Count) & NumberText
          End If
        End If
      End If

      If Len(MyNumber) > 2 Then
        'Remove last 3 converted digits from MyNumber.
        MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
      Else
        MyNumber = ""
      End If
      Count = Count + 1
  Loop

  If Count > 3 Then
    NumberText = NumberText & " de"
  End If

  ConvertIntegerToSpanish = NumberText
End Function

Function ConvertHundreds (MyNumber)
  Dim Result
  Dim Tens
  'Exit if there is nothing to convert.
  If CInt(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function

  'Append leading zeros to number.
  MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

  'Do we have a hundreds place digit to convert?
  If Left(MyNumber, 1) <> "0" Then
      If Left(MyNumber, 1) = 1 Then
        If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) = "0" AND Mid(MyNumber, 3, 1) = "0" Then
          Result = "Cien"              
        Else
          Result = "Ciento "
        End If
      Else
        Select Case CInt(Left(MyNumber, 1))
          Case 5: Result = "Quinientos "
          Case 7: Result = "Setecientos "
          Case 9: Result = "Novecientos "
          Case Else: Result = ConvertDigit(Left(MyNumber, 1)) & "cientos "
        End Select
      End If
  End If

  'Do we have a tens place digit to convert?
  If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
    If Len(Result) > 0 Then
      Result = Result & " " & ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
    Else
      Result = ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber,2))
    End If
  Else
      'If not, then convert the ones place digit.
      If Len(Result) > 0 Then
        Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
      Else
        Result = ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
      End If
  End If

  ConvertHundreds = Trim(Result)
End Function

Function ConvertTens (MyTens)
  Dim Result

  'Is value between 10 and 19?
  If CInt(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 1 Then
    Select Case CInt(MyTens)
      Case 10: Result = "Diez"
      Case 11: Result = "Once"
      Case 12: Result = "Doce"
      Case 13: Result = "Trece"
      Case 14: Result = "Catorce"
      Case 15: Result = "Quince"
      Case 16: Result = "Dieciseis"
      Case 17: Result = "Diecisiete"
      Case 18: Result = "Dieciocho"
      Case 19: Result = "Diecinueve"
      Case Else
    End Select
  Else
    '... otherwise it's between 20 and 99.
    IF CInt(Left(MyTens,1)) = 2 AND CInt(Right(MyTens,1)) > 0 Then
      Result = "Veinti" & LCase(ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1)))
    Else
      If CInt(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 2 AND CInt(Right(MyTens, 1)) = 0 Then
        Result = "Veinte"
      Else
        Select Case CInt(Left(MyTens, 1))
          Case 3: Result = "Treinta"
          Case 4: Result = "Cuarenta"
          Case 5: Result = "Cincuenta"
          Case 6: Result = "Sesenta"
          Case 7: Result = "Setenta"
          Case 8: Result = "Ochenta"
          Case 9: Result = "Noventa"
          Case Else
        End Select
        'Convert ones place digit.
        If CInt(Right(MyTens,1)) > 0 Then
            If(Result = "") Then
                Result = ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
            Else
                Result = Result & " y " & ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
            End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If

  ConvertTens = Result
End Function

Function ConvertDigit (MyDigit)
  Select Case CInt(MyDigit)
      Case 1: ConvertDigit = "Uno"
      Case 2: ConvertDigit = "Dos"
      Case 3: ConvertDigit = "Tres"
      Case 4: ConvertDigit = "Cuatro"
      Case 5: ConvertDigit = "Cinco"
      Case 6: ConvertDigit = "Seis"
      Case 7: ConvertDigit = "Siete"
      Case 8: ConvertDigit = "Ocho"
      Case 9: ConvertDigit = "Nueve"
      Case Else: ConvertDigit = ""
  End Select        
End Function
```